# Why does react-bootstrap not use my custom style?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a front end for my API, and I am using ReactJS, alont with react-bootstrap. I have always hated how bootstrap has only set colors for its buttons, and changing the button colors in vanilla html css is easy.

However, my `react-bootstrap/Button` instance never seems to actually use the custom CSS I've assigned to it. This is the styles I am trying to apply to the button, stored in `styles/style.css`

```
.accent {
    background-color: '#666a86';
    border-color: '#FFF'
}

.accent:hover {
    background-color: '#95b8d1';
}
```

I am importing this CSS file into my component like so:

```
import '../styles/style.css'
```

Note the component is stored in /components/ComponentName.jsx.
I have tried assigning the class to the Button component using `className`, as well as `bsClass` and neither make any difference. The only way I've been able to style the button is inline:

```
<Button style={{color:'#FFF'}}/>
```

Why is my button not being styled at all? It is still stuck to the befault blue bootstrap button.

**Update:**
Importing the bootstrap CSS within my CSS file actually worked:

```
.accent {
    background-color: #666a86;
    border-color: #FFF
}

.accent:hover {
    background-color: #95b8d1;
}

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: Try with <Button style={{color:'#FFF !important'}}/>

Comment: I think you can create custom css .class-for-button and use that class for you Button. For example <Button className={"class-for-button"} />. Hope it works

Comment: @HemadriDasari if you read my post at all, you would know I don't want to style it inline. I have far more styling than just one line.

Comment: You need to inspect the issue with the browser inspector. You will probably see why your new styles are not applied (maybe overridden by other?)

Comment: Are you importing the bootstrap stylesheet before or after you import your custom stylesheet? If you import bootstrap's styles after your custom styles, they will cascade over them - your custom styles will not render. Make sure you import your custom styles after bootstrap styles

Comment: See my edit @MikeAbeln

Comment: @JohnCarveth any guess as to why adding the import statement at the end works? I worked for me as well but I'm super curious as to why

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your css, remove the quotes from the color value

```
.accent {
  background-color: #666a86 ;
  border-color: #FFF ;
}

.accent:hover {
  background-color: #95b8d1;
}
```

see https://codesandbox.io/s/p9zq6mky4q

Comment: This actually didn't change anything. You can see the button has class 'accent btn btn-primary', however it is still the default style.